# How to make Google Authentication only available option in Meteor

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am creating an App in Meteor and I added some packages in order to allow my users to log in.

```
$ meteor add accounts-password accounts-ui accounts-google
```

Then I've put {{> loginButtons}} in the right place and configured Google API so everything works well.

But now users can do both: login via Google and create a new account inside my app. How to turn off the second feature? In other words I want to make authenticating via google the only available way of logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try removing accounts-password ?

```
meteor remove accounts-password
```